# Machine code error

Tags: boot, system-installation

I've been running Ubuntu 14.04 for almost a year now, and decided I want to try out 15.10.

Upon trying to boot the usb, I get "machine code error".

Details:
Install media: a dedicated partition on a 1tb seagate SL external usb hdd
Pc: Samsung aviv 8-series (np870z5g) (no cd drive)
Bios: secure boot is of, the current setup worked with 14.04 Ubuntu

What I tried:
Image from torrent and from website.
Doing a memtest (1 pass, no errors)

Edit: sorry forgot to mention I ran sudo update-grub with no result.
I tried turning uefi on, and now I booted into the live-cd. Is it bad to install a new Ubuntu in uefi? Will I be able to keep my /home partition?

Comment: please refer [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2207593) , run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not existing when running UEFI.

I did a complete reinstall with uefi on, and now everything is working flawlessly.